# How to upload pic from assets?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am using below code to upload the pic from gallery in flutter, if in case the pic is not picked up from the gallery I want the pic from the `assets` to be uploaded to the firebase storage, for that `avatarImageFile` should be equivalent to the image file from the assets.
How Can I achieve that?

```
Future getImage() async {
    print("get image");

    PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        final File file = File(image.path);
        avatarImageFile = file;
        isLoading = true;

      });
    }
    else{
      //if image is null then the image from the assets should be made picked into `avatarImageFile `

   }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter you can load your assets in two ways:

- Using `rootBundle.loadString("assets/my_file.json")` to load text files
- Using `rootBundle.load("assets/something.png")` to load any kind of file (images, pdf or any other kind of binary).

Note that `load` also works with .json files but in general loadString is a better choice when it comes to retrieving text. For more info, read the [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

```
avatarImageFile = await rootBundle.load("assets/a/b/c.png");
```

---

Do not use rootBundle when you're inside widgets: instead, prefer using [`DefaultAssetBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultAssetBundle-class.html):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget();

  Future<String> loadConfig(BuildContext context) async =>
    await DefaultAssetBundle
    .of(context)
    .loadString("myassets/some_cfg.json");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}

}
```

Again, do the above when you're inside widgets. In any other case, go for `rootBundle`.